# Why is need web.xml for during deploy web application on Weblogic, when I am using SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

I made web-app based on SpringBoot 2.x. I am using Intellij Idea 2019 and there I configure a deploy my webapplication on weblogic 12.x.

```xml
<dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

             <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I made *.xml

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/**dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/**weblogic.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd
                      http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
                      http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>web</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Then I made classes...

**WebLogicApplication.class**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebLogicApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebLogicApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**ServletInitializer.class**

```java
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebLogicApplication.class);
    }

}
```

**static content..**.

static/**index**.html

I set up Intellij to run a web application on the WebLogic server.

But I am getting errorors...

**one error**

```
<The log file C:\oracle_home_develop\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms, such as Windows.>  <10.02.2020 11:35:44,322 MSK> <Error> <Default> <BEA-000000> <Got an exception while rotating log file. java.lang.RuntimeException: com.bea.logging.LogRotationException: Error rotating log file C:\oracle_home_develop\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log  at com.bea.logging.LogFileRotator$1.run(LogFileRotator.java:254)    at com.bea.logging.LogFileRotator.executeGlobalAccountRunnerTask(LogFileRotator.java:243)   at com.bea.logging.LogFileRotator.rotate(LogFileRotator.java:248)
```

**second error**

> [2020-02-10 11:35:58,625] Artifact weblogic:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
>   <10.02.2020 11:35:58,915 MSK>    <[WebAppModule(weblogic_war_exploded:weblogic-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)] Error parsing descriptor in Web appplication "E:!_Install\git_hub_projects\weblogic\target\weblogic-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
>   weblogic.application.descriptor.MissingRootElementException: [Munger:2156204]The root element web-app is missing in the descriptor file E:!_Install\git_hub_projects\weblogic\target\weblogic-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/web.xml.
>       at weblogic.application.descriptor.BasicMunger2._onStartElement(BasicMunger2.java:506)
>       at weblogic.application.descriptor.BasicMunger2.next(BasicMunger2.java:441)
>       at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger._next(VersionMunger.java:346)
>       at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.next(VersionMunger.java:231)
>       at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.consumeInputStream(VersionMunger.java:599)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
> <10.02.2020 11:35:58,920 MSK>

**Update-1**

I fixed.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
                      http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>web</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

I deleted  src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/**dispatcherServlet-servlet**.xml

I checked *.war - there are not generated a web.xml

But, I again get an error

> [Munger:2156204]The root element web-app is missing in the descriptor file E:!_Install\git_hub_projects\weblogic\target\weblogic-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/web.xml.

**Update_3**

I changed an entry point...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebLogicApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebLogicApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(WebLogicApplication.class);
    }
}
```

and then

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>weblogic</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <version.apache.maven.plugins>3.8.1</version.apache.maven.plugins>
        <version.mapstruct>1.3.0.Final</version.mapstruct>

        <version.apache.common.lang3>3.9</version.apache.common.lang3>
        <version.apache.commons.text>1.8</version.apache.commons.text>
        <version.apache.commons.beanutils>1.9.4</version.apache.commons.beanutils>
        <version.datasource.proxy>1.6</version.datasource.proxy>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

             <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <!--исключаем из компиляции встроенный Tomcat-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

com.weblogic.weblogic.controller.**HomeController**

```java
@Controller
public class HomeController {


    private String message = "Hello World";

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getIndex() {

        return "index";
    }
}
```

I assembled again the project but I deployed straightforward on Weblogic (not with Intellij Idea) and I find again error

[http://172.17.89.177:7001/web]

> Error 500--Internal Server Error

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendContentError(ServletResponseImpl.java:738)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:796)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:713)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.sendErrorIfNecessary(ErrorPageFilter.java:349)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.getWriter(ErrorPageFilter.java:363)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:227)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
...

**Update_4**

**weblogic.xml**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
                      http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1.4.0</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>/api</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

I also created **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**. It is empty.

**src/main/webapp/index.html** and only it is here.

**Run/DebugCongiguration**

URL: http://localhost:7001/api

and everything else as usual

It is working now.

I think ... It need to create java-configuration. There is  will be described the rules an access to static content...

I've seen many examples where static content was in /resources. 
How do I design it now ? 
How to work in a bundle: Spring Bolt 2.x + Html + Weblogic ? 
How do I restrict access to static content ?

Who has any ideas how fix this ?

**Update**

I created the static content (*.html, *.css) under :

- src/main/resources/templates

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello Weblogic!</title>
    <link type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="st">
    Hello Weblogic!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

- src/main/resources/static/css/style.css
- Controller

```java
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

- pom.xml

```xml
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

- src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

</web-app>
```

- src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        https://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:context-root>sat</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

It works.

Comment: Your weblogic.xml makes it a servlet 2.5 application which requires a `web.xml`. Also you don't need the `dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml` it isn't even going to be read. Finally make sure that your build doesn't generate an empty `web.xml` in your `WEB-INF` directory!.